# React Native PDF - Complete Input

Tags: react-native, react-native-pdf

In my app I am able to **sign** some pdf.

Actually, after that the customer signed the document, we **tap on the pdf where we wants to place the signature**.

But we have to change this, because when we have a 30 pages pdf and the signature is at the end, we have to scroll so much.

So, we decided to **add an input** "signature" in the pdf, so the app could find this input and fill it with the signature, with the `x` and `y` position.

But **how can I fill a PDF input** with my image ?

Comment: Don't have the answer but a warning: this method is legally problematic. You need to go through a third like YouSign to authenticate the document.

Comment: give me access to your code i will help you.